# $\exp(-x-x^2) \leq 1-x$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Prove that 
$$\exp(-x-x^2) \leq 1-x$$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

I tried defining $f(x):= 1-x-\exp(-x-x^2)$ and calculating the derivative to see where $f$ is increasing/decreasing, but it didn't really get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the inequality is equivalent to the inequality

$$\log(1-x)\ge -x-x^2$$

Let $f$ be the function defined by

$$f(x)=\log(1-x)+x+x^2$$

Note that $f(0)=0$. Also note that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+1+2x>0$ for $0<x<1/2$.  Therefore, we have

$$f(x)\ge 0 \implies \log(1-x)\ge -x-x^2\implies 1-x\ge e^{-x-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: consider the function $$f(x)=\log(1-x)+x+x^2$$ and show that $$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{1-x}+1+2x>0$$ for all $x$ with $$0<x<\frac{1}{2}$$